# fuse holder block

Tags: fuse-holders, terminal-block

[image: Fuse and MOV Holder Block]

I have atached a picture of a multiple fuse and MOV holder. I tried searching for it online to buy, I can't find it, someone direct where to buy a similar multi fuse holder. Fuses are 20mm x 5mm, and they are as many as you see the wires going into the block. The item is traffic light controller cabinet.

Comment: Look for "DIN-Rail Fuse Terminal Block." We strictly do not recommend product brands nor places to purchase them, because that information changes quickly. However it can be useful to ask "What is this item called and how do I find it?"

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A larger picture would be nice...

From what I can see, that is a group of DIN-rail single fuse holders.  You should be able to find them among DIN-rail terminal blocks and accessories.

Comment: Thanks, helped, found it.